# Suppress MVC invalid route errors in Elmah

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, error-handling, elmah, error-logging

I would like to suppress/ignore the error in Elmah:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The incoming request does not match any route.
```

I have filtered out 404 errors but the above error still comes through if someone types an invalid route/address.

Answer (score 0):

can add a listener to global.asax (easy) or use a regex expression in web.config. For global.asax add

```
 void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception.Message.Contains("The incoming request does not match any route"))
            e.Dismiss(); 
    }
```

The prevents it from being logged to the email module but not the db module. You can do one or both. See [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering)